# WF4 Instances and Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, workflow-foundation-4

I'm developing a Win Service app that hosts a WF service and a WF application on a Windows 7 machine. When I deploy it to a 2008 Server machine, my logs document activity from the Win Service but not from either of my Workflows. It's running under LocalSystem, would that cause my issue or is there another problem hosting WFs on a 2008 Server machine that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the WorkflowServiceHost to expose your workflows though WCF? And if so can you reach the endpoints that it is supposed to create? You can also add the EtwTrackingProvider  so you can see what your workflows are doing in the Windows event log.